# Python aiogram проблема с await

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Пишу простенького бота на aiogram с помощью states. С ними проблем нет, но есть проблема в вызове функции, если значение передаваемое стейтом совподает с конкретным.

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'admin_verification' was never awaited
> admin_verification('admin')
> RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Ниже пример проблемы:

```
class Admin(StatesGroup):
   ver = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
async def admin_verification(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Введите пароль для доступа к панели администратора")
    await Admin.ver.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Admin)
async def ver_access(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["ver"] = message.text
        if message.text != 'babki2023': #вот тут пошли ошибки 
            message.answer("Пароль был введён неверно. Попробуйте еще раз.")
            state.finish()
            admin_verification("admin")
        elif message.text == "/start":
            start_message('start')
    await state.finish()
```

Буду очень благодарен, если поможете и объясните, как эту проблему решить)

Comment: await добавьте где надо

Comment: Если функция async, то вызывать ее нужно с await (если очень сильно упрощать)

Comment: @СергейШ я добавлял, там вылетает в ошибку, когда передаю в функцию строку. Сегодня попробую ещё раз

Comment: @insolor , я попробую сегодня переделать немного, но там выдает ошибки при использовании await, мол у str нет метода answer

Comment: await admin_verification(message)

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо) попробую так

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо, помогло сильно))